# why the list behaves differently in python and Java?

Tags: java, python, arrays, list, for-loop

I am learning the scripting language, python. I know Java quite a bit. I am trying to translate one bit of code from Java to python. but they behave erratically (or my understanding could be totally wrong)
I have the following code in Java, where I am adding elements to a ArrayList indefinitely.
so this causes outofmemory error, which I expect:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Testing{
public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(4);
        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            list.add(5);
        }
}
}
```

now the same code translated in python:

```
lst = []
lst.append(5)
lst.append(4)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst.append(5)
print lst
```

here I get the output: `[5, 4, 5, 5]`

from what I see, is the list not passed as a reference to the `for` loop in python?

similarly here,

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> for i in l[:]:
...    l.append(4)
...    print l
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

in each iteration inside the `for` loop, I am increasing the list size, so the iteration should go forever correct?

Comment: Does python only do the check for the size once? Java evaluates the `for` condition every loop iteration.

Comment: Why would Python loop forever? The `range()` result is calculated **once**, not for each loop iteration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A python `for` loop evaluates the expression that yields the iterable over which to loop **once** only. You can manipulate the `lst` object in the loop without affecting the outcome of what `for` is looping over. This differs from the Java `for` construct (which is a very different construct from the Python `for` statement, which is really a [Foreach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) construct), which evaluates the 3 associated expressions for each iteration.

In your first example, you created a `range()` result, and once that is created it is not updated for each loop iteration.

In your second example, you created a copy of `lst` using a full-length slice (`lst[:]`) for the loop to iterate over. The copy is not re-created for each loop iteration.

There is a caveat here, however. The `for` loop calls [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) on the object-to-be-iterated-over. For a list object, the resulting list iterator does keep a reference to the original list, as well as an iteration index. Every time the `for` loop advances the iterator (calling [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on it), the iteration index is incremented and looked up on the original list, until the index is equal to the list length. If you keep adding to the list in the loop, that *would* create an infinite loop.

You can see this if you do *not* create a copy of the list to iterate over:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in L:
...     L.append(4)
...     print L
...     if len(L) > 30:
...         break
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Here, the iterator created for `L` keeps yielding the next element as `L` is extended in the loop, and if I had not added a length limit in the loop this would have continued forever.

Comment: Thanks!. that makes sense. in Java, as other mentioned, the list.size is calculated for each iteration. I thought in python, len(lst) is calculated for each iteration and the range is determined by the new len. now I understand that the iterable over is evaluated only once

Comment: The caveat might be a little confusing, because it doesn't apply to either of his examples. It's obvious what you mean to anyone who already understands it, but for the OP it might help to show an example of when you actually _are_ iterating the list itself. (Otherwise, great answer.)

Answer (score 6):

`range(len(lst))` creates the range once, and then iterates over that whereas in java `list.size()` is evaluated at each iteration

Answer (score 2):

> > is the list not passed as reference to the for-loop in python?

All objects are passed by reference in Python, and in Python *everything* is an object.  (Java primitive values are not, but even plain integer and float values are objects in Python.)

> > in each iteration inside for-loop, I am increasing the list size, so the iteration should go forever correct?

You are increasing the size of l, that's correct, but l[:] is evaluated just once and produces a shallow copy of l.  That copy isn't changed in the loop, so changes to l inside the loop do not change the set of values that the loop variable will take on.

Change l[:] to just l in that loop, and then you'll see a lot of output.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easiest to explain this by translating the `for` loops into their equivalent `while` loops.

In Java:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    list.add(5);
}

int i=0;
while (i<list.size()) {
    list.add(5);
    ++i;
}
```

In Python pseudocode:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst.append(5)

_r = range(len(lst))
_i = iter(r)
while _i isn't done:
    next(_i)
    lst.append(5)
```

In practice, you don't really need to understand how `iter`* and `next` work, or the details of how the "_i isn't done" part works**; the key is that a `for` loop creates an iterator, then iterates over it. In your case, it's creating an iterator over a `range` object (or, in Python 2.x, the `list` returned by the `range` function).

But even without knowing that, you can see that your `len(lst)` is only being evaluated once at the start, to create the iterator, while the Java `list.size()` equivalent is being evaluated each time through the loop.

---

If you want the equivalent of a Java-style `for` loop, you have to write the `while` loop explicitly.

---

* `iter` creates an iterator over any iterable (a list, a range, even another iterator). An iterator is sort of like a smart object that has a reference to the iterable and a "current position" within it, although under the covers they're rarely implemented that way. Calling `next` on an iterator effectively returns the value at the current position and advances the iterator to the next one (or the equivalent for however the iterator is actually implemented).

** What actually happens is, in effect, a `try:`/`except StopIteration:`, because calling `next` on an iterator that's done raises `StopIteration`. Of course it's implemented in C (or Java or .NET or RPython, for other Python implementations), and the C actually uses some special magic code for looping over an iterator that makes it a little faster, but almost nobody ever needs to think about that part.